# Multiplatform ARMv5 Linux kernel

Tags: linux, arm, embedded-linux, device-tree

How Linux detects board running it?

I see number of `dts` compiled in one `dtb` file. And **how to force** kernel to use one from another board?

How to read `DT_MACHINE structure` with Debian Aqueeze, Linux 2.6 on unknown board?

How to detect memory region?

Comment: *"How Linux detects board running it?"* -- Simple, it doesn't.  On ARM, even in the days when ATAGs and machine ID were used, the Linux kernel is informed (i.e. told) what the board is.  If the kernel could *"detect"* the board and it configuration, then you wouldn't need ATAGs or DT.  *"I see number of dts compiled in one dtb file"* -- No, one **.dts** file produces one **.dtb** file.  The ARM Linux kernel is simply provided the memory address of where the one **.dtb** has been placed in memory by the boot program.

Comment: @sawdust how get board name on old Linux 2.6 to make dtb for this board?

Comment: ARM Linux 2.6 does not support Device Tree.

Comment: @sawdust I know. but i need board name and possibly addresses for hardware.

Comment: It's not obvious what *"you know"*, and you have provided zero background information on the issue.  The boot program passes the MACH_TYPE number to the ARM kernel; if that number has been registered, then you could come up with a board name.  The boot log will  have something useful.

Comment: How it passed? To memory, boot arg or something else? Is there way to extract info needed to make dts from old linux?

Comment: From https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/arm/Booting : *"The boot loader must ultimately be able to provide a MACH_TYPE_xxx
value to the kernel. ...  This should be passed to the kernel in register **r1**."*